# How should I do, if I want to use cocoapods in a react native project

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I want to use a API about the map, but the official website didn't provide API about react native. So I want to install it in Cocoapods. But I encountered a error when I installing it. The error:
[image]

I don't know how to handle it. I think that it is different from the original iOS in some directory.Vert thank you if you can give some ideas.
The profile:
[image]

Comment: Show you `PodFile`. Apparently, it's wrong, because you put twice `yszxzffc-tvOSTTests` in it.

Comment: @Larme thanks your help

Comment: Avoid putting screenshots, prefer copy/paste text. In your case, it's harder to me to write `yszxzfrc-tvOSTests` rather than just copy it. Well, you wrote twice `taget 'yszxzfrc-tvOSTests' do`. Why ? That's your issue.

Comment: @Larme Ok,Thanks you tips.I solved it after I deleted about taget 'yszxzfrc-tvOSTests. And I don't know why. I just run a command pod init